# Which line continuations are valid and which ones are invalid in shell scripting for POSIX shell?

Tags: shell, posix

In the following example, although I have split the line `if true && true` into two lines, it works fine and produces the output `hi`.

```
if true &&
   true
then
    echo hi
fi
```

But in the following example, where the redirection operator and the filename has been split into two different lines, I get an error.

```
wc -l <
/var/log/messages
```

The error I get is,

```
foo.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
foo.sh: line 1: `wc -l <'
```

Is there a rule defined by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) that I can use to easily understand where line continuations are valid and where they aren't?

Comment: Easily? Maybe not. Thoroughly: [2.10 Shell Grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10) Specifically `AND_IF` and `io_file`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to search for "control operators" in the POSIX Shell Command Language document (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html)

Some excerpts:

> [2.9.1 Simple Commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_01)
>
> > A "simple command" is a sequence of optional variable assignments and redirections, in any sequence, optionally followed by words and redirections, terminated by a control operator.
>
> [2.9.2 Pipelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_02)
>
> > A *pipeline* is a sequence of one or more commands separated by the control operator '|'.
>
> [2.9.3 Lists](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_03)
>
> > An AND-OR list is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by the operators "&&" and "||" .
> >
> > A list is a sequence of one or more AND-OR lists separated by the operators ';' and '&' and optionally terminated by ';', '&', or .

According to the [grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_10_02), the control operators that can be followed by a `linebreak` are:

- `&&` and `||`
- `|`
- `;` and `&`

Additionally, for and while loops, if and case statements, function definitions and subshell and grouping constructs can have liberal numbers of newlines in them.

Answer (score 0):

Easily? Maybe not.

Thoroughly? [2.10 Shell Grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10).

Specifically `AND_IF` and `io_file`.

> ```
> %token  AND_IF    OR_IF    DSEMI
> /*      '&&'      '||'     ';;'    */
>
> and_or       :                         pipeline
>              | and_or AND_IF linebreak pipeline
>              | and_or OR_IF  linebreak pipeline
>
> command         : simple_command
>                 | compound_command
>                 | compound_command redirect_list
>                 | function_definition
> redirect_list   :               io_redirect
>                 | redirect_list io_redirect
>                 ;
> io_redirect     :           io_file
>                 | IO_NUMBER io_file
>                 |           io_here
>                 | IO_NUMBER io_here
>                 ;
> io_file         : '<'       filename
>                 | LESSAND   filename
>                 | '>'       filename
>                 | GREATAND  filename
>                 | DGREAT    filename
>                 | LESSGREAT filename
>                 | CLOBBER   filename
>                 ;
> filename        : WORD                      /* Apply rule 2 */
> ```